# im trying to make a prime number and composite number game and it always print "correct answer" even if you put the wrong answer

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a prime and composite number game in which you will identify the number as prime or composite but it always prints "correct answer".

I've tried using breaks and putting other sections in the outside loop but still get the wrong statement.

```
import random
a = "composite number"
b = "prime number"
num = random.randint(2 , 10)
print(num)
guess = str(input("tell if it is composite number or prime number: "))
for i in range (2,num):
    if (num % i) == 0: 
        num == a
    else: 
        num == b
### I think this section is the wrong one. It only prints "correct answer" even if I intend to write the wrong answer

if guess == a:  
    print("correct answer")
elif guess == b:
    print("correct answer")
elif guess != b:
    print("wrong answer")
elif guess != a:
    print("wrong answer")
```

I'm expecting that it will show the right statement on whether it is the right answer or the wrong answer

Comment: Look at your logic.  You compare `guess` to `a` and if it matches you say it's correct.  Otherwise, you compare it to `b` and it that matches, you again say it's correct.  So regardless of whether the user says it's prime or composite, you always say it's the correct answer.  The only time you say it's wrong is if the user enters a bad string.  Also, `num == a` and `num == b` are comparisons, so they serve no purpose.  But even if you change them to assignments, you would be assigning strings to `num`.  The intended logic of that loop is unclear, but at present it's not doing anything.

Comment: You are calculating the value of num, but you are not using that calculation in your if statements...

Also, because you did an if-elif-elif-elif clause, it will never get to the latter two unless you put a gibberish answer like "comp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code. First, in the `for` loop, you are using comparison (`==`) instead of assigment (`=`), but anyway, even if you meant the latter, you are not using `num` later in the code. Also the `print` at the end is wrong.

Last thing, you can optimize the `for`loop in two ways: iterating from `2` to `sqrt(num)` and breaking as soon you find that `num` is not prime.

```
import random
import math

a = "composite number"
b = "prime number"
num = random.randint(2 , 10)
print(num)
guess = str(input("tell if it is composite number or prime number: "))

for i in range (2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
    if (num % i) == 0: 
        answer = a
        break
else:
    answer = b

if answer == guess:  
    print("correct answer")
else:
    print("correct answer")
```

Comment: what is the use of +1 ?

Comment: It's necessary because the second argument of `range` is not inclusive.